# Appending to 2 dimensional array in python

Tags: python, list

I am reading Data from `CSV` file which comes similar to the below matrix/array

```
b = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

I would like to change the index of every element greater than 1 to a new row in the arraylist

this will make the above array as below

```
b = [[1,2],[5,6],[9,10],[3,4],[7,8][11,12]]
```

what i have done in python  (but couldn't get the answer)

```
b = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
c = b
rows = len(b)
columns = len(b[0])
c[4].append(1)
count = 3
for i in  range(rows):
 for j in  range(columns):
     if i > 1:
         for k in columns
             list1 = 
             c.insert(count,list1)
             count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just split it into two lists, and then recombine them?

```
new_elements = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    if len(b[i]) > 2:
        new_elements.append(b[i][2:])
    b[i] = b[i][:2]
b.extend(new_elements)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy`. Perform [`indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) and [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) at the end:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
print(np.concatenate((b[:,:2], b[:,2:])))

# [[ 1  2]
#  [ 5  6]                                                    
#  [ 9 10]                                                  
#  [ 3  4]                 
#  [ 7  8]                                                     
#  [11 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data =[]
data.append(['a',1])
data.append(['b',2])
data.append(['c',3])
data.append(['d',4])
print(data)
```

## output

[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4]]

Answer (score 1):

### One line solution `np.array(b).reshape(-1,2)`:

```
import numpy as np
b = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

np.array(b).reshape(-1,2)
```

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10],
       [11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
b = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
n = 2
b = [j[i:i+n] for j in b for i in range(0, len(j), n)]
b = b[0::2] + b[1::2]
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10], [3, 4], [7, 8], [11, 12]]
```

Comment: Rakesh, thanks for the quick response but the answer should be  [[1,2],[5,6],[9,10],[3,4],[7,8][11,12]]

Comment: the data actually represent the below

Comment: studentID  StudentName  MathGrade ScienceGrade  studentID  StudentName  MathGrade ScienceGrade  studentID  StudentName  MathGrade ScienceGrade   (all students data comes in rows which i try to get in column)

Comment: Updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use numpy arrays and the [concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) function.

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]) # or b = np.array(b)
c = np.concatenate((b[:, :2], b[:, 2:]),0)
```

If you prefer working with python arrays, you can use list interpretation:

```
c = [row[:2] for row in b]
c.extend([row[2:] for row in b])
```

which returns

```
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10], [3, 4], [7, 8], [11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be this:

```
b = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

step = 2
length = len(b[0])
b = [elem[i:i+step] for i in range(0,length,step) for elem in b]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [9, 10], [3, 4], [7, 8], [11, 12]]
```